# How is type cast executed on hardware?

Tags: c, cpu

In C, sometimes we cast data type for arithmetic operations, for example:

```
int a = (int)b + (int)c;
```

What does a type cast look like to CPU? What instructions does type cast compile into (x86)? Does type cast harm CPU pipelines?

Comment: Depends on what the types are.

Comment: What are the types of `b` and `c`?

Comment: A type cast looks like nothing to the CPU, because it never sees it. It's only meaningful to the compiler, at the time the code is being compiled.

Comment: @KenWhite: Surely, that's not necessarily true (assuming `b` and `c` are variables rather than compile-time constants)? I mean not the cast itself, but the instructions necessary to widen, say, a `short` to an `int`.

Comment: Splitting hairs, the CPU never sees the *cast*. But the compiler may compile the cast down to one or more CPU instructions that perform the data conversion.

Comment: If you are casting between integral types it might be that there is nothing necessary to be done except emitting different instructions for arithmetic. In that case, the cast is free.

Comment: @KenWhite, I think that's not that helpful, as it implies the compiler emits no code for a cast. Which it frequently does. And the OP specifically asks 'what instructions does type cast compile into?'

Comment: @Roddy, that's not what I said at all. I said the CPU sees nothing of the cast; it sees the instructions that the **compiler emitted** for the cast. The CPU itself has no information regarding the fact that a cast was done; it has information about what is there after the fact. I addressed the first question: "What does a type cast look like to CPU?", which is "whatever code was emitted by the compiler as the result of the typecast". It has no knowledge that the compiler performed a typecast. The CPU might receive an instruction as a result of that typecast, but it doesn't know that's why.

Comment: @Mysticial: Splitting hairs, that doesn't affect what I said at all. The CPU never knows (or even cares) that the cast was done. The CPU just knows it needs to process the instructions the compiler emitted as a result of its having seen the typecast.

Comment: @KenWhite *You earned the **Paraphraser** badge!*

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Actually, no. I said it first. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the types involved, obviously. Some casts are just a matter of interpretation, so involve no instructions - eg, `unsigned int` to `int`.

Others may require 'widening' of the data to propagate the sign bit into the high order bits, for example `signed char` to `int`.

The instruction on X86 used for this is `cbw` or `cwde`. http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/cbw.htm

ex: `signed char 0b10000000` must become `int 0b1111111110000000` (for 16-bit int)

Answer (score 2):

If b is, say, a float; the compiler will generate code to call a library subroutine of the nature of `convert_float_to_int()`. That's usually not something done directly in hardware. It *might* be in-lined, if the routine is fairly short.

Comment: that's helpful, thanks, could you please elaborate little more on that - some reading materials maybe?

Answer (score 2):

That's very architecture and datatype-specific. Static casts like that could be a register-to-register move, a no-op, they could set or clear CPU flags, logically mask bytes, etc.. If `b` is a float, for example, then the temporary will have to be filled with whatever the CPU's floating point integer conversion mechanism yields. If it's a  `char` then it will be the two's complement (possibly sign-extended) value. If it's `unsigned char` then the temporary will contain the value of b in its LSB and zeros in the more significant bytes. Really the only way to tell is to look at the generated code (in `gcc` this is the `-S` option). A floating point move could certainly cause a pipeline stall or bubble. These days you have the complication that it might even end up in a GPU.